# Excepciones con diferentes ejecuciones

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo una duda con las excepciones, en este ejercicio se pide que se contemplen 2 excepciones: Una que informe sobre el problema (y que no detenga la ejecución del programa. es lo que entiendo yo), y otra que sí produzca una interrupción, y por tanto, se detenga la ejecución con su correspondiente error.
Creo que he creado correctamente el método y excepción para la caso de la interrupción, pero dudo si están correctamente construídos.
Agradezco cualquier respuesta que me aclare cómo usar mejor las excepciones, o la manera correcta de utilizarlas.

**Enunciado Ejercicio**

Construir una clase FacturaEmitida que descienda de la clase Factura y que incluya los atributos emisor (empresa que emite la factura) y cliente y al menos, un método llamado imprimirFactura que muestre todos los atributos (tanto los heredados de Factura como de FacturaEmitida). 
La clase Factura dispondrá de los atributos: CIF (alfanumérico), numero de factura y total. Esta clase tendrá un único constructor al que se le pasará por parámetros estos atributos y los inicializará. 
Se deberán de contemplar las siguientes excepciones:

- Importe negativo: producirá una interrupción en el programa si el
  atributo total se almacena con una cantidad negativa.
- Emisor en blanco: será informativo, y se producirá si se inicializa
  el emisor con la cadena vacía. Todos los atributos serán privados y
  además de los métodos indicados en el enunciado, se deberán de crear
  aquellos que se estimen conveniente que hagan falta.

FacturaEmitida.java

```
public class FacturaEmitida extends Factura {

    private String emisor;
    private String cliente;

    FacturaEmitida(String cif, int numFactura, double total, String emisor, String cliente){

        super(cif,numFactura,total);
        this.emisor = emisor;
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public void imprimirFactura() {

        System.out.println("CIF: " + this.getCif() + "\n" +
                            "Número de factura: " + this.getNumFactura() + "\n" +
                            "Emisor: " + this.getEmisor() + "\n" +
                            "Cliente: " + this.getCliente() + "\n" +
                            "Total: " + this.getTotal() + "\n");
    }

    public class ValorNoValido extends Exception{
        public ValorNoValido(){ }
        public ValorNoValido(String cadena){
                 super(cadena); //Llama al constructor de Exception y le pasa el contenido de cadena
        }
    }

    public void comprobarImporte() throws ValorNoValido {

          if(this.getTotal() < 0){
              throw new ValorNoValido("El importe total no puede ser negativo.");
          }         
    }

    public String comprobarEmisor(String emisor){
    //name.trim().length() == 0
    if (this.getEmisor() == "" || this.getEmisor() == null) {
        this.emisor = "";
        throw new RuntimeException("El campo de Emisor no puede quedar vacío.");        
    }
    return emisor;

}

    /**
     * @return the emisor
     */
    public String getEmisor() {
        return emisor;
    }

    /**
     * @param emisor the emisor to set
     */
    public void setEmisor(String emisor) {
        this.emisor = emisor;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cliente
     */
    public String getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param cliente the cliente to set
     */
    public void setCliente(String cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

}
```

Factura.java

```
public class Factura {

private String cif;
private int numFactura;
private double total;

Factura(String cif, int numFactura, double total){
        this.cif = cif;
        this.numFactura = numFactura;
        this.total = total;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cif
     */
    public String getCif() {
        return cif;
    }

    /**
     * @param cif the cif to set
     */
    public void setCif(String cif) {
        this.cif = cif;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numFactura
     */
    public int getNumFactura() {
        return numFactura;
    }

    /**
     * @param numFactura the numFactura to set
     */
    public void setNumFactura(int numFactura) {
        this.numFactura = numFactura;
    }

    /**
     * @return the total
     */
    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * @param total the total to set
     */
    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FacturaEmitida fact = new FacturaEmitida("844571X", 222, 1500, "", "Weist Cheing");
        try {
        fact.comprobarImporte();
        fact.comprobarEmisor(fact.getEmisor());
        fact.imprimirFactura();
        }catch (FacturaEmitida.ValorNoValido e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

De la manera como lo tienes definido actualmente el programa se interrumpirá en los dos tipos de excepciones, no llegando a ejecutar la linea `fact.imprimirFactura();` en caso de presentarse cualquiera de las excepciones, debería quedar algo así para logra lo que dice el enunciado:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FacturaEmitida fact = new FacturaEmitida("844571X", 222, 1500, "", "Weist Cheing");
    try {
        fact.comprobarImporte();
        try {
            fact.comprobarEmisor(fact.getEmisor());
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        fact.imprimirFactura();
        }catch (FacturaEmitida.ValorNoValido e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo tu planteamiento de esta manera :

1. Si importe es negativo **EXCEPCION**
2. Si emisor esta en blanco **INFORMAR**

Cito tu pregunta

> Emisor en blanco: será informativo

Por lo tanto el unico pero que veo en tu codigo quitar la excepcion y solo INFORMAR :

```
public String comprobarEmisor(String emisor){
//name.trim().length() == 0
if (this.getEmisor() == "" || this.getEmisor() == null) {
    this.emisor = "";
    System.out.println("El campo de Emisor es vacío.");        
}
return emisor;
```

Si pruebas esto, la unica excepcion (y por ende interrumpir le ejecucion de imprimir la factura) se dara cuando el valor del importe sea negativo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FacturaEmitida fact = new FacturaEmitida("844571X", 222, 1500, "", "Weist Cheing");
    try {
        fact.comprobarImporte();
        fact.comprobarEmisor(fact.getEmisor());
        fact.imprimirFactura();
    }catch (FacturaEmitida.ValorNoValido e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```